# Im getting an empty cursor when trying to get all the elements from a row by ID

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

im trying to get all the elements of a row in sqlite by ID using a cursor. The cursor is not null, but i can't seem to operate with the cursor, Here is my code:

```
    public Book getBookByid (int itemId) {

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tables[0] + " WHERE " + SQLiteHelper.ITEM_ID + " = " + itemId;
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            Book bookRead = new Book();
            if(cursor!=null) {
                Log.i("myApp","cursor not null");
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    Log.i("myApp","title" + cursor.getColumnIndex(arrayFields.get(0)[1]));
                    bookRead.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(arrayFields.get(0)[1])));
                    bookRead.setGenre(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(arrayFields.get(0)[2])));
                    bookRead.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(arrayFields.get(0)[3])));
                    bookRead.setRecommendation(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(arrayFields.get(0)[4])));
                    bookRead.setPhoto(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(arrayFields.get(0)[5])));
                    bookRead.setLike(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(arrayFields.get(0)[6])));
                }
                Log.i("myApp","title" + bookRead.getTitle());
       }
       cursor.close();
     return bookRead;
}
```

The problem is that the code does not enter the if(cursor.moveToFirst()) so i cannot assing the values to my object, getting a null object reference.

My logs show the following:

```
05-13 09:37:23.720  13918-13918/com.appforbrands.meloapunto I/myApp﹕ cursor not null
05-13 09:37:23.720  13918-13918/com.appforbrands.meloapunto I/myApp﹕ titlenull
```

I'm also getting a blue warning or error in logcat:

```
05-13 10:04:14.555    3969-3969/com.appforbrands.meloapunto W/Bundle﹕ Key itemId expected Integer but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value 0 was returned.
05-13 10:04:14.559    3969-3969/com.appforbrands.meloapunto W/Bundle﹕ Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
```

Comment: First of all check your curcor count i.e. `int count = cursor.getcount();` . check is it positive?

Comment: @Andrain I get 0 when i do `cursor.getCount();` it should return the number of rows that i have on my table right?

Comment: yes it will return no of rows count. its means that there is a error in your query or there no data in your database table @niendo

Comment: Try to select this way: `String strFilter = SQLiteHelper.ITEM_ID + "=" + itemId;
Cursor cursor = database.query(tables[0], arrayFields, strFilter, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: Use the **DDMS** to get your sqlite database and check if your data with **itemId** exists. here how to get your app sqlite database : [link](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/12/18/android-emulator-sqlite-database-location)

Answer (score 1):

This is steps you need to do to debug your function:

1. Make sure you have valid database connection.
2. Check and make sure your raw query are correct.
3. The itemID is exist in your data.

Comment: Yes I have checked all of the steps from above, I have a ListView where i list all of my database rows. The problem is when trying to get a specific one by id to retrieve all of the information from the row

Comment: Did you try to log your raw query and execute the query on a DBMS?
Log.i("myApp", selectQuery);

Comment: Well, no. I don't know how to interact with my db so I can see the structure and verify its components

Comment: See [this link] (http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/12/18/android-emulator-sqlite-database-location) for detail how to work with your local sqlite DB.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite may be confused finding your id in your Sqlite book table, so the query can't find  any row. Check your table definitions or manually write the table id in your query String.